# Get round brackets with apalike

Tags: apa-style, brackets

When forming my bibliography, I use

`\bibliographystyle{apalike}`

However that leads to in text references to use square brackets.

I was wondering if it is possible for me to change the brackets to round brackets?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This might be useful http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39248/need-to-change-citation-format-from-1-to-a, if you’re using the `article` document class or similar.

Comment: Are you loading the package `apalike` too?

Answer (score 8):

Add

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
```

to your preamble.  For regular in text citations, use

```
\citet{<key>} % or \cite{<key>}
```

and for citations enclosed in parentheses use

```
\citep{<key>}
```

See the `natbib` documentation for more details.

(You can also load the `apalike` package as Marco suggests in the comments, but the `natbib` solution is to be preferred since with `apalike` you only get the whole citation surrounded by parentheses, which is usually not the preferred method.)

Comment: I ended up putting

\usepackage{apalike}

It did exactly what i wanted to, thanks everyone!

Comment: How, please? How.