# Lettered (rather than numbered) citations and natbib's compress option

Tags: natbib

A while back, you provided a very helpful answer to the following post:

[Need to change citation format from [1] to (a)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39248/need-to-change-citation-format-from-1-to-a)

I had a follow-up question regarding your answer.  When I implement your TeX, everything works perfectly, but the `[compress]` option of the [`cite`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cite) package stops working.  That is, I get

some text (a,b,c,d)

instead of

some text (a-d)

How can I restore the functionality of the `[compress]` option?

Comment: Please consider explaining *which* of the solutions there you are trying to use. Adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to this question would also make it easier to help you.

Comment: And welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: `natbib` is a different beast.  From p.18 of its manual, "It is impossible to make the cite and natbib packages compatible,
since both reimplement \cite from scratch. Instead, I have taken over
some of the coding from cite.sty, modifying it for natbib. This coding
is activated by including one of the options sort or sort&compress in the
\usepackage command."  Thus, know that there is a `compress` option to `\usepackage[compress]{natbib}`.

Comment: Please see latest revision, which I believe simplifies the fix and also eliminates the errors on pass 1 of the compile.

Answer (score 3):

REVISED ANSWER:

I have developed a more compact fix to this problem that I think is even more general than the original answer (which is retained below, in case I have over-reached on this answer).  It amounts to patching `natbib.sty` in the following two ways:

1. It replaces all occurrences of `\svcitenumfont{}` with `\svcitenumfont{\alphalph{}}`, and
2. It patches`\@lbibitem` in one place.

EDITED to trap null arguments to `\alphalph` on pass 1 of the compile, by using macro `\xalphalph`.

The code required for this fix is simply the following:

```
\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\def\xalphalph#1{\if\relax#1\relax\else\alphalph{#1}\fi}
\let\svcitenumfont\citenumfont
\renewcommand\citenumfont[1]{\svcitenumfont{\alphalph{#1}}}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@lbibitem}{{\NAT@num}}{{\xalphalph{\NAT@num}}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

These changes produces the same result as my original answer.  Additionally, they have been confirmed to work when the `compress` and/or the `numbers` package options are turned on or off.  Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,ifthen,filecontents}
\usepackage[compress,numbers,round]{natbib}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\def\xalphalph#1{\if\relax#1\relax\else\alphalph{#1}\fi}
\let\svcitenumfont\citenumfont
\renewcommand\citenumfont[1]{\svcitenumfont{\alphalph{#1}}}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@lbibitem}{{\NAT@num}}{{\xalphalph{\NAT@num}}}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},  year = {2001},  title = {Alpha}}
@misc{A01b,
  author = {Author, A.},  year = {2001},  title = {Alpha TWO}}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},  year = {2002},  title = {Bravo}}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},  year = {2003},  title = {Charlie}}
@misc{D04,
  author = {Duthor, D.},  year = {2004},  title = {Delta}}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
cite \cite{A01, A01b, B02, C03, D04}\par
and \cite{A01} and \cite{A01,D04}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

Through much trial and error, I found three places in `natbib.sty` for this MWE, in which (in the ORIGINAL solution) the macro `\NAT@num` gets replaced with `\char\numexpr\NAT@num+96\relax` which effectively turns "1" into "a", "2" into "b", etc.  If different package options are set, there are likely more places where this alteration will be needed (the difficulty is in figuring out which ones).

The three package macros that were revised for this MWE include `\NAT@citea@mbox`, `\def@NAT@last@yr`, and `\@lbibitem`.  Here is the MWE.

EDIT: Taking Werner's suggestion to use the `alphalph` package, in the event that there are more than 26 references, one would instead `\usepackage{alphalph}` and change `\NAT@num` into `\alphalph{\NAT@num}` for the affected locations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,ifthen,filecontents}
\usepackage[compress,numbers,round]{natbib}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\makeatletter
\def\NAT@citea@mbox{%
 \@citea\mbox{\NAT@hyper@{{\citenumfont{\alphalph{\NAT@num}}}}}%
}%
\def\def@NAT@last@yr#1{%
 \protected@edef\NAT@last@yr{%
  #1%
  \noexpand\mbox{%
   \noexpand\hyper@natlinkstart{\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}%
   {\noexpand\citenumfont{\alphalph{\NAT@num}}}%
   \noexpand\hyper@natlinkend
  }%
 }%
}%
\def\@lbibitem[#1]#2{%
  \if\relax\@extra@b@citeb\relax\else
    \@ifundefined{br@#2\@extra@b@citeb}{}{%
     \@namedef{br@#2}{\@nameuse{br@#2\@extra@b@citeb}}%
    }%
  \fi
  \@ifundefined{b@#2\@extra@b@citeb}{%
   \def\NAT@num{}%
  }{%
   \NAT@parse{#2}%
  }%
  \def\NAT@tmp{#1}%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\bibitemOpen\csname NAT@b@open@#2\endcsname
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\bibitemShut\csname NAT@b@shut@#2\endcsname
  \@ifnum{\NAT@merge>\@ne}{%
   \NAT@bibitem@first@sw{%
    \@firstoftwo
   }{%
    \@ifundefined{NAT@b*@#2}{%
     \@firstoftwo
    }{%
     \expandafter\def\expandafter\NAT@num\expandafter{\the\c@NAT@ctr}%
     \@secondoftwo
    }%
   }%
  }{%
   \@firstoftwo
  }%
  {%
   \global\advance\c@NAT@ctr\@ne
   \@ifx{\NAT@tmp\@empty}{\@firstoftwo}{%
    \@secondoftwo
   }%
   {%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\NAT@num\expandafter{\the\c@NAT@ctr}%
    \global\NAT@stdbsttrue
   }{}%
   \bibitem@fin
   \item[\hfil\NAT@anchor{#2}{\alphalph{\NAT@num}}]%
   \global\let\NAT@bibitem@first@sw\@secondoftwo
   \NAT@bibitem@init
  }%
  {%
   \NAT@anchor{#2}{}%
   \NAT@bibitem@cont
   \bibitem@fin
  }%
  \@ifx{\NAT@tmp\@empty}{%
    \NAT@wrout{\the\c@NAT@ctr}{}{}{}{#2}%
  }{%
    \expandafter\NAT@ifcmd\NAT@tmp(@)(@)\@nil{#2}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha}
}
@misc{A01b,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha TWO}
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo}
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie}
}
@misc{D04,
  author = {Duthor, D.},
  year = {2004},
  title = {Delta}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
cite \cite{A01, A01b, B02, C03, D04}

and \cite{A01} and \cite{A01,D04}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps consider using [`alphalph`](http://ctan.org/pkg/alphalph) instead, as you may run into problems when you run out of letters.