# hyperref is not dereferencing citations after citation format is changed to alphabetical

Tags: bibliographies, xetex, hyperref

I converted citation format to alphabetical according to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39254/116920) answer. But, it created an abnormal behavior in hyperref. Although the citations are still clickable in the PDF, nothing happens when I click on them. *(With hyperref, when a citation is clicked, it should be dereferenced and the PDF viewer should jump to bibliography page where the citation was declared.)*

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref, lipsum}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@bibitem[1]{\item\if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout{%
\string\bibcite{#1}{\theenumiv}}\fi\ignorespaces} %%% instead of \the\value{\@listctr}

\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\refname}
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\alph{enumiv}}}% %% instead of "\@arabic\c@enumiv"
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\alph{enumiv}}}% 
                                    %% instead of "\@arabic\c@enumiv"
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
    {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\cite{A1}
\lipsum[2]
\pagebreak
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{A1}{John (2011)} 
\bibitem{B1}{Carl (2015)}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Any idea how to fix it? I am using XeLaTeX engine to compile the document. (Because I intend to use package polyglossia later.)

**My attempts to identify the problem:**

After a little investigation, it became clear that when I renewed *only* `\@bibitem` command and not `\thebibliography` environment, the citation dereferencing error still remained.

Then I tried the following code, which is completely identical to the original definition of `\@bibitem` according to the [LaTeX Bibliography manual](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltbibl.dtx). The error is here too.

Can anyone explain what is exactly happening?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref, lipsum}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@bibitem[1]{\item\if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout{%
\string\bibcite{#1}{\the\value{\@listctr}}}\fi\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\cite{A1}
\lipsum[2]
\pagebreak
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{A1}{John (2011)} 
\bibitem{B1}{Carl (2015)}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: why not use BibTeX or Biber in conjunction with `biblatex`? In the same question you linked there's a [solution for `biblatex` by lockstep](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39249/81905)

Comment: The answer you appear to be referring to deals with a much more contained issue, viz., how to change the numeric-type citation call-outs from the default style to a different, but fundamentally still numeric style. As such, the answer in question is not a good basis for coding a switch to an authoryear-type citation call-out style. Also, that answer makes no provisions for interacting with `hyperref`. Instead of modifying `\@bibitem` directly, I'd make use of the `natbib` package and provide the required new pieces of information in the optional argument of each `\bibitem` instruction.

Comment: @Mico, I wanted alphabetical style numbering, ie- [a] John(2011) [b] Carl(2015). And when cited I wanted them to be appear like [a], [b] etc. If you run my MWE, you'll see that's what I was doing. The author year format was used for just a sample bibliography.

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid I understand even less now what you're objective is.

Comment: @Mico, Please run my MWE, and click on the first citation (ie \cite{A1}) in the PDF.  One would expect to be forwarded to the References page (ie next page), but nothing happens. That is what I want to 'fix'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that the `hyperref` package has to be loaded after you have redefined the bib commands since it modifies them, too. I suggest to modify `\bibitem` and `\thebibliography` a little bit less invasive.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref, lipsum}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@bibitem{\the\value}{\alph}{}{}
\xpatchcmd\thebibliography{\@arabic}{\@alph}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Oh, yes, classic `xpatch`. It worked. Thanks, @gernot